# how to call inbound channel in java code

Tags: spring-integration

i have a channel

```html
<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter
    channel="transactionChannel" entity-manager="entityManager"
    jpa-query="select t from Transaction t where t.transactionStatus=:transactionStatus"
    expect-single-result="false">
    <int-jpa:parameter name="transactionStatus" expression="payload['transactionStatus']" />
</int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

i want to call this channel from java code so that i can pass transactionStatus to get record from DB, as i need to use it in many class , please tell me how can i invoke through java code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that - when creating the adapter with XML, the framework requires a poller to be configured.

You can create a `JpaPollingChannelAdapter` programmatically (Java config) and call its `receive()` method.

See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/jpa.html#_configuring_with_java_configuration_14) for an example, but **don't** add the `@InboundChannelAdapter` annotation.